# How to handle Firefox browser confirmation messages in Test Automation?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am currently working on the **selenium+java** **test automation project**.
I have encountered a problem that while running many test classes together in testng.xml, **firefox display
[image: Fire Fox confirmation popup] confirm resubmission popup.** when I am running a single class this message does not popup. This confirmation popup comes when the last set of classes begins to run. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: This is a non issue. identify first why the "Erro was encountered" message appears and try to fix that.

Comment: It is not always an option to fix the web app. In this case the ask is for the solution how to workaround the problem in test automation. It is not a query for how to fix the web app.

Answer (score 0):

May be, you can try to simulate pressing Enter key or Spacebar and see if that works.

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public void pressEsc(WebDriver driver) {
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```